# Async upload multiple files and getting their urls in firebase storage problem

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, firebase-storage

So basically my problem lies within the title. I have one image, than i have multiple files upload input. I want to add them to firebase storage. I do that, it works fine, the problem comes when i want to take those download urls. In this case, taking urls for multiple files works fine,when i want to pass it to this separated image file, it just ends up being null. By the way i am using vue.js. So here is the code of methods i use, all the inputs are fine.

```
methods:{
   async uploadImageFile() {
     var slugify = require('slugify')
     let imageName = this.$refs.image.files[0].name.split(".")[0]
     let ext = this.$refs.image.files[0]['name'].split(".")[1]
     this.blog.image = slugify(imageName)
     const {canvas} = this.$refs.cropper.getResult();
     if (canvas) {
       canvas.toBlob( blob => {
         let uploadTask = storageRef.child('blogs/' + this.blog.image +"-"+ moment().unix()+ "." +ext)
         try {
           uploadTask.put(blob)
           let downloadURL = uploadTask.getDownloadURL()
           this.blog.imageUrl = downloadURL
         }
         catch (error){
           console.log(error)
         }
       });
     }
   },
   save() {
     let slugify = require("slugify")
     this.blog.slug = slugify(this.blog.title)
     this.blog.user = usersCollection.doc(this.$store.state.userProfile.uid)
     this.blog.active = false
     this.blog.created = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())
     blogsCollection.add(this.blog).then(() => {
       router.push('/admin/blogs');
     }).catch((error) => {
       console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
     });
   },
   async saveFiles(){
     await this.uploadImageFile()
     for(const fileIndex in this.files){
       let timestamp = new Date()
       let fileObject = this.files[fileIndex]
       let fileNameName = fileObject.name
       let ext = fileObject.name.split(".")[1]
       try {
         let uploadTask = storageRef.child('blogs/' + fileNameName.split(".")[0] + "-" + timestamp.getTime().toString() + "." + ext)
         await uploadTask.put(fileObject)
         let downloadURL = await uploadTask.getDownloadURL()
         this.blog.files.push({fileName:fileNameName,
           fileURL:downloadURL})
       } catch (error){
         console.log(error)
       }
     }
     this.save()
   }
}
```

I set the @click method for saveFiles() function..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i figured it out 2 hours after posting the question, but forgot to check for any possible answer. So the deal here is there is a big load of async functions happening here. So the best thing for me was to create the sort of chain of functions. First do the saveFiles, then uploadImage and then Save. One possible warkaround was in uploadImage function, where i pick the cropper's content and turn it into blob so i could upload it to storage, there i could call async and await for blob to finish uploading so i could take the url of image accordingly. I will post the edited code that works and does what i want.

```
    async saveFiles(){
      if(!this.files){
        this.uploadImageFile()
        return
      }else {
        let slugify = require("slugify")
        for (const fileIndex in this.files) {
          let timestamp = new Date()
          let fileObject = this.files[fileIndex]
          let ext = fileObject.name.split(".")[1]
          let fileNameName = slugify(fileObject.name.split(".")[0]) + "-" + 
    timestamp.getTime().toString() + "." + ext
          try {
            let uploadTask = storageRef.child('blogs/' + fileNameName)
            await uploadTask.put(fileObject)
            let downloadURL = await uploadTask.getDownloadURL()
            this.blog.files.push({
              fileName: fileNameName,
              fileURL: downloadURL
            })
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
          }
        }
        //here we call the uploadImageFile
        this.uploadImageFile() 
      }
    },
    //then we have the uploadImageFile func
    uploadImageFile() {
      var slugify = require('slugify')
      let imageName = this.$refs.image.files[0].name.split(".")[0]
      let ext = this.$refs.image.files[0]['name'].split(".")[1]
      this.blog.image = slugify(imageName)+"-"+moment().unix() + "." + ext
      const {canvas} = this.$refs.cropper.getResult();
      if (canvas) {
        canvas.toBlob(blob => {
          let uploadTask = storageRef.child('blogs/' + this.blog.image ).put(blob)
          uploadTask.on('state_changed',
              (snapshot) => {
                switch (snapshot.state) {
                  case firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED: // or 'paused'
                    break;
                  case firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING: // or 'running'
                    break;
                }
              },
              (error) => {
                console.log(error);
              },
              () => {
                this.save(uploadTask)
              }
          );
        }, 'image/jpeg');
      }
      this.save()
    },
    //then we have the save
    save(uploadTask){
      let task = uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
      task.then((url)=> {
        this.blog.imageUrl = url
        let slugify = require("slugify")
        this.blog.slug = slugify(this.blog.title)
        this.blog.user = usersCollection.doc(this.$store.state.userProfile.uid)
        this.blog.active = false
        this.blog.created = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())
        this.blog.type = this.selected
        blogsCollection.add(this.blog).then(() => {
          router.push('/admin/blogs');
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
        });
      })
    }
```

Now this block of functions is doing what i intended. Upload file then take the download url of that file. Previous code was executing and didn't wait for urls because there was to much things happening at the same time, and it dind't wait for url responses. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you import `firebase` as `fb`

Try something like this:

```
let uploadTask = storageRef.child('blogs/' + fileNameName.split(".")[0] + "-" + timestamp.getTime().toString() + "." + ext)
await uploadTask.put(fileObject)    
fb.UploadTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.future;
Uri downloadUrl = await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
url1 = downloadUrl.toString();
```

`url1` will be your string with download url